# How many sessions can be managed by an Java Application in Struts 2?

Tags: java, session, struts2, actioncontext

I am working on Transaction Management application, and I am using Struts2.
I have used internally a session for setting and getting values like

```
ActionContext.getContext().getSession().put("string", string);
```

Is there any limit or any disadvantage of using a session like this in the application?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11699132/1654265

Comment: I guess OP is concerned about the usage of S2 session wrapper map.

Comment: I guess OP is not even aware of the difference, he's probably just wondering about how much garbage can he safely put in memory... until he'll shape the question better, ours will remain only guesses in the wild, though

Comment: @AndreaLigios-- limit (size) of data that a HTTPSession variable can hold  in application with multiple user sessions

Comment: *quod erat demonstrandum* :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Limit is the size of your computers physical memory.you dont store dynamic values in session because someone can modify them in the meanwhile , so store only those values in session which represent any user specific data or static  values (i.e. which are not going to be changed while session exists).

**Note :** static here is not [static](http://www.javatpoint.com/static-keyword-in-java) keyword .

Answer (score 2):

There's no limit. The session in Struts 2 is implemented as a `Map` to simplify access to servlet session's attributes.

I have written in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20565841/573032) answer:

> The `SessionMap` is specifically designed for the purposes if you want to have access to the servlet session attributes. So, the user is able to keep a synchronized collection of objects in session and use it instead of `HttpSession` directly.

I know only one disadvantage if you get the session from the action context, it might return `null`. The solution is in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24270155/573032) answer.

> There are two methods to obtain a session map to the action:
>
> 1. Implement `SessionAware`. By default the session map is populated on action call. This is a preferable way.
> 2. Get a session map from the action context. This way you should make sure the request is handled by the Struts2 filter.

The first method is *preferred*, as explained in the docs page, allows you use a session in tests.

Answer (score 0):

It's your size of the internal/physical memory of the system. The session is create a singleton class in your war file.The war file is stored in your Server. The server is in your C: folder in windows. So the session is depends on your physical memory.